# Need advice recovering money lost due to debit card fraud! Bank wont help!

Tags: united-states, credit-card, fraud, consumer-protection

I was recently the victim of credit card fraud. My number and some of my info was compromised and subsequently used to run up about $500 worth of online charges within a week's time.

This was on my Bank of America VISA Debit card. I reported this to Bank of America after verifying I still had the card in my possession an I was certain the charges were not mine. BoA immediately cancelled the card and issued me a replacement.

After a few days I was issued a temporary credit for the total, while an investigation was done.

About a month later I received a notice stating that my claim had been denied and the temporary credit had been reversed. I was furious. They gave me little or no explanation (the CSR I talked to was basically reading verbatim from some policy manual and could offer no explanation or details about my case). I pleaded with them to reconsider, at while point she said she could request the case be re-reviewed. She told me without any new information it would most likely be denied again.

The best reason I could get from anyone was that BoA investigators contacted a "few" of the merchants involved (They would not tell me which ones or even how many), and they were able to "verify my information". To me, this means that the criminal using my card had also gotten hold of my name and mailing address, obviously since that's generally required to get a charge approved.

Is this complete incompetency on the part of BofA? What are my recourses? I was not expecting this level of difficulty and felt covered by the VISA promise of "Zero Liability". I contacted VISA directly and pleaded my case to them, and after lots of back and forth I was forwarded to a Credit Card Fraud department which went to voicemail. I have not yet heard back from them 2 days later.

Please help!

Comment: This is exactly why I NEVER use debit cards (too risky), and exclusively use credit unions instead of commercial banks (who couldn't give a rat's ass about their customers).

Comment: It really makes me sad to hear this story.  These banks are too big to fail, take tax payer bailouts, and then keep on screwing with little guys.  $500 is nothing to them but everything to people like me and probably Mark.

Comment: I can't speak for BOA, but before you get too upset about them taking the bailout money you should understand that most of the banks that did were threatened with severe consequences if they didn't take the bailout, which was a loan at above market interest rates. That said, I have no love for BOA regardless of current events.

Comment: @JohnFx - please don't bring sanity and rationality to my knee-jerk reactions and scape goating. =)

Comment: @Mark, did you get it sorted?

Comment: If they're denying the credit they think it wasn't actually fraud.

Comment: You could have tried contacting your branch manager, or a regional manager, or a regional director, or someone even higher up.  Or you could have tried the Better Business Bureau or a government agency.  But, before you contact any bank manager, government, or other agency, please read [this](http://elliott.org/help/how-to-fix-your-trip/) then [this](http://elliott.org/contacts/bank-of-america/).

Comment: I'm not sure of the laws which apply here, nor am I sure of the terms and conditions you agreed to when signing up for your debit card. If a fraud artist stole your money using your debit card number, then of course the bank would prefer not to reimburse you. But perhaps they were legally _required_ to reimburse you, in which case they should have done so. Either way, the bank gave you a very unsatisfactory explanation of what happened, and _that_ is poor customer service.

Comment: Dear OP:  what happened in the end?  Did you ever hear back from VISA's fraud department?

Answer (score 14):

The best way to get satisfaction is report them to the appropriate agency that regulates the bank.

This is usually the Office of Comptroller of Currency (OCC), but some banks are regulated by a different agency. However, start with these guys. They can refer you to the right agency if it isn't them.

[Here is a link to their consumer complaints page](http://www.occ.treas.gov/customer.htm)

The other banks are regulated by the Federal Reserve Board. Here is their consumer complaint page: http://www.federalreserveconsumerhelp.gov

Given the current environment where the Government is threatening more regulation of the financial industry, the last thing the banks want right now is a lot of complaints on file, so they have a lot of incentive to try and make you happy if you show that you know who to tattle to.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know what the legal situation in the US is, but in the UK I would take the bank to court. Your case is simple - you never authorised the transactions, and they have provided no evidence to you that you did. The details of the VISA "zero liability" promise you mention may also be worth quoting as it ought to form part of your contract with the bank.